# How to throw a 404 error on Ajax error in order to direct to default 404 behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Working in: ASP.NET MVC 3, JavaScript, jQuery. The web.config file is setup to handle HTTP 404 errors. Specifically, it will provide proper redirection upon invalid URL's like www.mysite.com/INVALIDURL (i.e. a 404 Page not found)

Question: is there a way to default to that same behavior within an Ajax error? Or in other words, how do I throw a 404 'Page not found' response within an ajax error.

```
$.ajax ({ ... })
  .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // throw 404 Page not found HTTP error
  }
```

Edit1: the end result I am looking for is to provide a 'Page not found' display upon an Ajax error

Edit2: I already have an redirection setting within the web.config file like so

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/error/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

I would like the ajax.error to default to that behavior, is it possible?

Comment: You can't throw a 404 error from JavaScript (that doesn't make sense).  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - you are wanting to redirect to a 404 page on ajax error?  As stated, you cannot throw a 404, but you can redirect to another page.

```
$.ajax ({ ... })
  .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     window.location.href = '/My404ErrorPage';
  }
```

**EDIT**

If you do not want the URL to change - you are going to need to most likely look into using a modal dialog/alert box/special div to convey this information to the user and place the message that you want to use in that.  Below assumes that NotFound is the id of a div on your page somewhere and leverages off of jquery UI for the first part, plain ol' alert box for the second.

```
$.ajax ({ ... })
  .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     $('#NotFound').html('Some error message');
     $('#NotFound').Dialog();
     //OR you could do
     alert('Some error message');
  }
```

Comment: Right, but what if I wanted to preserve the invalid URL and display a "Page not found" to the user?

Say the input url was: www.mywebsite.com/query?SOMEID1

I want the user to be able to see the incorrect url, and fix it accordingly.

Like so: www.mywebsite.com/query?SOMEID

Comment: @Dannalieth: I'm a little confused here.  Why would an AJAX need to "throw a 404 error"?  If you go to that URL, why not have the *server* throw a 404 if needed?

Comment: Because I am calling another service from the ajax call, ie perform a query based on SOMEID (in the above example). The query result is associated with a particular webpage, hence the 404 error can only be thrown after the ajax(query) has been executed.

Comment: Well - there is no way to preserve the URL and redirect to a 404 not found page.  Even in the .NET handler for errors, you are redirected and the path that errored is appended to the URL (I think it is appended).

Comment: @Dannaleith - Users should not be manually typing in IDs anyways...I would assume they are a) entering from a textbox to search or b) clicking a link that your app generates...

Comment: Yes, what you said in your edit is the best alternative: create an error dialog that displays the error message. Thanks Tommy

Answer (score 0):

try to set up js redirect to error page with "ajaxSetup". For example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend  : function(){showLoader()},
    complete    : function(){hideLoader()},
    error       : function(){redirTo404()}
});
```

so it will use this as default for all ajax calls